# WPF - context menu over DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

My `DataGrid` is bound to a data source, which is a database. When user right clicks somewhere over the `DataGrid` control, I'd like to be able to recognize over which column he or she did it. Scenario is as follows - if `ContextMenu` is opened over a column holding dates, then (for example) I would like to present him with options to filter out dates smaller, greater or equal to the date selected.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
        <Helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext}">
            <MenuItem Header="Cokolwiek" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.FK}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.PlacementTarget.DataContext}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

`PlacementTarget` is a reference to the `DataGrid`, and I'd like it to be a reference to DataGridColumn.

BindingProxy class:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable {
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
        typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is hook up to the `PreviewMouseUp` event so you can look at the `Source` property of the `Event` that is raised.

> With the exception of direct events, WPF defines most routed events in pairs - one tunnelling and the other bubbling. The tunnelling event name always begins with 'Preview' and is raised first. This gives parents the chance to see the event before it reaches the child. This is followed by the bubbling counterpart. In most cases, you will handle only the bubbling one. The Preview would be usually used to
>
> block the event (e.Handled = true) cause the parent to do something in
>   advance to normal event handling.

e.g. if UI Tree = Button contains Grid contains Canvas contains Ellipse
Clicking on the ellipse would result in (MouseDownButton is eaten up by Button and Click is raised instead.)

```
private void OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        var source = mouseButtonEventArgs.Source;
        // Assuming the DataGridColumn's Template is just a TextBlock
        // but depending on the Template which for sure should at least inherit from FrameworkElement to have the Parent property.
        var textBlock = source as TextBlock;
        // Not a good check to know if it is a holding dates but it should give you the idea on what to do
        if (textBlock != null)
        {
            var dataGridColumn = textBlock.Parent as DataGridColumn;
            if (dataGridColumn != null)
            {
                if ((string) dataGridColumn.Header == "Holding Dates")
                {
                    // Show context menu for holding dates
                }

            }
        }
            // Other stuff
        else if (somethingElse)
        {
            // Show context menu for other stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: I added event handlers to PreviewMouseUp properties on `DataGrid`, `ContextMenu`, and `MenuItem`, but still dataGridColumn in every of these is null...

Comment: Try climbing the `Visual Tree` and see for the `Parent` if any of these are `GridColumn`. I believe you are right clicking on the `template` of a `Column` which can be a `TextBlock`

Comment: Umm... I know it's a beginner's question, but could you point me to a direction showing how should I do that?

Comment: Thanks, but I discovered that you need to use the `OriginalSource` property, otherwise casting `source as TextBlock` will result in `null` value. Anyway, thank you very much, I've been struggling with it for a few hours :)